# Optimizing processing of data stored in a flat file

Tags: c#

At my office we use an old third-party tool to handle some data processing and export work. The output of this tool is unfortunately in a really clunky format, so for us to put it into a meaningful form and work with it, we have to have an intermediate processing step between the raw export of this data and our ability to act further on it.

This problem was one that I pretty concisely solved some time ago in Python with itertools, but for *reasons*, I need to relocate this work into an existing C# application.

I've super-generalized and simplified the example data that I've posted here (and the corresponding code), but it's representative of the way the real data is set up. The raw data spit out by the tool looks like this, with some caveats (which I'll explain):

```
Zip Code:      11111
First Name:    Joe
Last Name:     Smith
ID:            1
Phone Number:  555-555-1111
Zip Code:      11111
First Name:    John
Last Name:     Doe
ID:            2
Phone Number:  555-555-1112
Zip Code:      11111
First Name:    Mike
Last Name:     Jones
ID:            3
Phone Number:  555-555-1113
```

There are no unique separators between records. They're just listed one right after the other. A valid and actionable record contains all five items ("Zip Code", "First Name", "Last Name", "ID", "Phone Number").

We only need first/last name, ID, and phone number for our purposes. Each unique record always begins with Zip Code, but thanks to some quirks in the underlying process and the third-party tool, I have some things I need to account for:

- Records missing a phone number are invalid, and will show up with a value of "(n/a)" in the "Phone Number" line. We need to ignore the whole record in this case.
- Records (rarely) may be missing a line (such as "Last Name") if the record was not entered correctly prior to processing. We ignore these cases, too.
- If there was an error with some linked information to the underlying data, the record will contain a line beginning with "Error". Its exact position among the other items in a record varies. If a record contains an error, we ignore it.

The way I solved this in C# is to start with the first line and check to see if it begins with "Zip Code". If so, I drop into a further loop where I build a dictionary of keys and values (splitting on the first ":") until I hit the next "Zip Code" line. It then repeats and rolls through the process again while `current line < (line count - 5)`.

```
private void CrappilyHandleExportLines(List<string> RawExportLines)
{
    int lineNumber = 0;
    while (lineNumber < (RawExportLines.Count - 5))
    {
        // The lineGroup dict will represent the record we're currently processing
        Dictionary<string, string> lineGroup = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // If the current line begins with "Zip Code", this means we've reached another record to process
        if (RawExportLines[lineNumber++].StartsWith("Zip Code"))
        {
            // If the line does NOT begin with "Zip Code", we assume it's another part of the record we're already 
            // working on.
            while (!RawExportLines[lineNumber].StartsWith("Zip Code"))
            {
                // Append everything except "Error" lines to the record we're working on, as stored in lineGroup
                if (!RawExportLines[lineNumber].StartsWith("Error")
                {
                    string[] splitLine = RawExportLines[lineNumber].Split(new[] { ":" }, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    lineGroup[splitLine[0].Trim()] = splitLine[1].Trim();
                }

                lineNumber++;
            }
        }

        // Validate the record before continuing. verifyAllKeys is just a method that does a check of the key list
        // against a list of expected keys using Except to make sure all of the items that we require are present.
        if (verifyAllKeys(new List<string>(lineGroup.Keys)) || (lineGroup["Phone Number"] != "(n/a)"))
        {
            // The record is good! Now we can do something with it:
            WorkOnProcessedRecord(lineGroup); 
        }
    }
}
```

This works (from my initial testing, at least). The problem is that I *really dislike* this code. I know there's a better way to do it, but I'm not as strong in C# as I'd like to be so I think I'm missing out on some ways that would allow me to more elegantly and safely get the desired result.

Can anyone lend a hand to point me in the right direction as to how I can implement a better solution? Thank you!

Comment: I haven't used it in a long while, but something like this can work with non-delimited files: https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers

Comment: You wrote in the title 'optimizing'. Is your primary concern making the code more elegant/robust, or is it making it as fast as possible? An idea of the number of records might help identify if the speed of this matters at all.

Comment: @MineR Good point, and my apologies for not clarifying that! "Optimizing" was probably not the best choice for wording. Generally, it will be dealing with somewhere in the neighborhood of 100-200 records in any given hour. So there aren't typically _that_ many to worry about. Performance is certainly a concern, but I think the bigger issue from my perspective is that the code performing this work be clean, reliable, and maintainable. My solution works, but I think it fails 2 (if not all 3) of those criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to solve the problem in a bit more of an object oriented manner using a factory-ish pattern.

```
//Define a class to hold all people we get, which might be empty or have problems in them.
public class PersonText
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    public bool Error { get; set; }
    public bool Anything { get; set; }
}

//A class to hold a key ("First Name"), and a way to set the respective item on the PersonText class correctly.
public class PersonItemGetSets
{
    public string Key { get; }
    public Func<PersonText, string> Getter { get; }
    public Action<PersonText, string> Setter { get; }

    public PersonItemGetSets(string key, Action<PersonText, string> setter, Func<PersonText, string> getter)
    {
        Getter = getter;
        Key = key;
        Setter = setter;
    }
}

//This will get people from the lines of text
public static IEnumerable<PersonText> GetPeople(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    var itemGetSets = new List<PersonItemGetSets>()
    {
        new PersonItemGetSets("First Name", (p, s) =>  p.FirstName = s, p => p.FirstName),
        new PersonItemGetSets("Last Name", (p, s) =>  p.LastName = s, p => p.LastName),
        new PersonItemGetSets("Phone Number", (p, s) =>  p.PhoneNumber = s, p => p.PhoneNumber),
        new PersonItemGetSets("ID", (p, s) =>  p.ID = s, p => p.ID),
        new PersonItemGetSets("Zip Code", (p, s) =>  p.ZipCode = s, p => p.ZipCode),
    };

    foreach (var person in GetRawPeople(lines, itemGetSets, "Error"))
    {
        if (IsValidPerson(person, itemGetSets))
            yield return person;
    }
}

//Used to determine if a PersonText is valid and if it is worth processing.
private static bool IsValidPerson(PersonText p, IReadOnlyList<PersonItemGetSets> itemGetSets)
{
    if (itemGetSets.Any(x => x.Getter(p) == null))
        return false;
    if (p.Error)
        return false;
    if (!p.Anything)
        return false;
    if (p.PhoneNumber.Length != 12) // "555-555-5555".Length = 12
        return false;

    return true;
}

//Read through each line, and return all potential people, but don't validate whether they're correct at this time.
private static IEnumerable<PersonText> GetRawPeople(IEnumerable<string> lines, IReadOnlyList<PersonItemGetSets> itemGetSets, string errorToken)
{
    var person = new PersonText();


    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        var parts = line.Split(':');
        bool valid = false;

        if (parts.Length == 2)
        {
            var left = parts[0];
            var right = parts[1].Trim();

            foreach (var igs in itemGetSets)
            {
                if (left.Equals(igs.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    valid = true;
                    person.Anything = true;
                    if (igs.Getter(person) != null)
                    {
                        yield return person;
                        person = new PersonText();
                    }
                    igs.Setter(person, right);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (parts.Length == 1)
        {
            if (parts[0].Trim().Equals(errorToken, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                person.Error = true;
            }
        }
        if (!valid)
        {
            if (person.Anything)
            {
                yield return person;
                person = new PersonText();
            }
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (person.Anything)
        yield return person;
}
```

Have a look at the code working here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xVnATX

Answer (score 2):

This may help you, the idea is grouping entries based on their id by dictionary, then you can validate enitries with appropriate conditions:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = @"t.txt";
    var text = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.UTF8);
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    var id = "";
    var rows = text
        .Select(l => new { prop = l.Split(':')[0], val = l.Split(':')[1].Trim() })
        .ToList();

    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        if (row.prop == "ID")
        {
            id = row.val;
        }
        else if (dict.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            dict[id].Add(row.prop, row.val);
        }
        else
        {
            dict[id] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict[id].Add(row.prop, row.val);
        }
    }

   //get valid entries
   var validEntries = dict.Where(e =>e.Value.Keys.Intersect(new List<string> { "Zip Code", "First Name", "Last Name", "Phone Number" }).Count()==4 && e.Value["Phone Number"] != "(n/a)").ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x => x.Value);
}
```

In case *ID* is related to previous properties and emerges after them you can use below code as *If* block :

```
if (row.prop == "ID")
{
        var values=dict[id];
        dict.Remove(id);
        dict.Add(row.val,values);
        id = "";
}
```